# How to download images with difference highlighted in Applitools?

Tags: java, selenium, applitools

I am trying to download diff image of base and checkpoint url created by applitools.

I found test result handler which does this. Here is the link:

https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007188111-TestResultsHandler-a-way-to-download-diffs-baseline-and-current-images

While running repo I am getting errors.

How to make it work? Anyone has example that works?

I am using java selenium.

Comment: What errors you're getting? Post the code you're using.

Comment: import com.sun.glass.ui.Size;

Gives error.  

So i gave following:dependency>
 <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
 <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
 <version>12.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: After giving dependency still i get more errors

Comment: Nobody is knowing what you're doing with "I gave dependency", "Gives error", etc. You need to post what code you run the error message you receive. An "error" could be cause by anything.

Comment: Java project repo is provided in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the Applitools technical support team. I understand that you're running into an issue with downloading the diff images when using the TestResultsHandler class in Java.

It is tough to say exactly what the issue is that you're experiencing without seeing the error messages  as well as your code. In any case, [here is an example](https://github.com/applitools/TestResultsHandler-Java/blob/master/src/main/java/DownloadDiffExample.java) of the TestResultsHandler usage.

Alternatively, you can also use the [Eyes Utilities JAR](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007188371-Eyes-Utilities) which also provides the  capability of downloading the differences.

Lastly, if you're still running into issues, please feel free to reach out to us directly by opening a ticket via [this web form](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).